# Laravel head content appearing in body tag

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create my first layout for a new site I'm making.

The problem I am having is that content I want in the `<head>` is going into `<body>`, and `<head>` is empty.

I have:

**layout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@section('title')</title>
        {{ HTML::style('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'); }}
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>@yield('h1')</h1>
        @yield('content')
        {{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'); }}
        {{ HTML::script('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'); }}
    </body>
</html>
```

**users.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('title')
    Users Page - 1

@section('h1')
    <?PHP echo $h1;?>
@stop
```

Where am I going wrong?

Also what is the *difference* in `@yeild` and `@section` in my view?

Comment: There might be a problem elsewhere on the page and your browser is just restructuring.  If you view source, the items in your head tag will probably actually be in the head tag.  You also would need a `@stop` after your section tag as well.  It might be causing the problem

Comment: wow, help me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in **layout.blade.php**. You are extending this blade template, so you should use `@yield('title')` in `<title>` tag ,and you should `@stop` every `@section`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        {{ HTML::style('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'); }}
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>@yield('h1')</h1>
    @yield('content')
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'); }}
    {{ HTML::script('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'); }}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing @stop

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should use `yield` to dump out the content, for example, if you have a mastwer layout like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you may use in your child view something like this:

```
extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
   Everything within this section will be dumped
   in to `@yield('content')` in your master layout.
@stop
```

You should use `@stop` for any section to close that section. Probably you may try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ $title }}</title>
        {{ HTML::style('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
    </head>
    <body>

        @yield('content')

        {{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'); }}
        {{ HTML::script('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'); }}
    </body>
</html>
```

From your `controller` you may pass the title like:

```
return View::make('viewname')->with('title', $title);
```

Read more in about `Templates` on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/templates).

Comment: +1 for the detailed info. Do you think it's better practice to send in things like the title data via the view or the controller (as in return View::make('viewname')->with('title', $title); as opposed to using '@yeild' '@section' etc?

Comment: Yes, it's more dynamic.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean via the template or view?

Comment: From Controller to view.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, though the cause was different.  There were two @includes that were in the source that came BEFORE the @section('body').  We don't know why this would cause the header issue, but it did. It was

```
@extends('layouts.plane')
@include("layouts.modal-quote-create")
@include("layouts.modal-mulch-types")
@section('body')
```

and we changed it to:

```
@extends('layouts.plane')
@section('body')   
@include("layouts.modal-quote-create")
@include("layouts.modal-mulch-types")
```

and that took care of the issue.